# No check condition in for loop but the loop still terminate C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, operator-overloading

I have this program in C++ that have one simple for loop, the for loop has no check condition:

```
for (std::string a_word; std::cin >> a_word;) {
  // code goes here
}

// Code after the loop
```

I compiled them and run on terminal, when I hit Ctrl + D (EOF), the for loop then stopped and run code after the loop, although there is no check condition, can anybody explain what happened under the hood?

Comment: I was silly, the check condition is in the second part, after the first semicolon, i was paranoid to think it's after second semicolon

Answer (score 7):

You are mistaken. There is a condition in the loop

```
for (std::string a_word; std::cin >> a_word;) {
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  // code goes here
}
```

It is

```
std::cin >> a_word;
```

Any expression (or declaration) in this part of the for statement is contextually converted to type `bool`.

From the C++ STandard (6.4 Selection statements)

> 4. ...The value of a condition that is an expression is the value of the expression, **contextually converted to bool** for statements other
>      than switch;

There is defined explicit operator for streams in the C++ Standatrd

```
explicit operator bool() const;
```

that returns `!fail()`.

Expression `std::cin >> a_word;` returns reference to `std::cin` and the conversion operator shown above is applied.

So when you pressed `Ctrl + D` then `fail()` returns `true` and the condition of the loop (`!fail()`)is equal to `false`.

Comment: Excellent answer. Deleting mine. :)

Answer (score 0):

But you *do* have a condition in the loop. Any stream [can be used in a condition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool), and the input operator `>>` returns the stream.

Answer (score 0):

`istream& istream::operator>>(T&)` returns an istream object which is convertible to bool (`operator bool() const`) and converts to false when there's a error condition (EOS or Ctrl+D qualify as an error condition).